# How do I append a class to my body tag using RenderBody()

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

So as of right now, I'm using my _Layout.cshtml page to build the header, body and footer, and in the bodu I'm doing this in order to render my Index page:

```html
<body class="darkDesign">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

And my index page is just the default one that comes with the template:

```html
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
```

The issue is that I want to add a class to the `body` tag but it won't render it because it seems as RenderBody dynamically renders the body tag for me and this is what it looks like in the DOM editor in Chrome.

[image: example]

How do I properly add the class to the body tag?

Comment: `RenderBody` doesn't *dynamically render* the body, look at the layout template, the `body` tag is explicit there. You even have the class `darkDesign` there.

Comment: Yet it doesn't render in the DOM, why is that?

Comment: I don't see `<!--Loader starts-->` in your source code, so I think you using some JS library/frameword, if so make sure that library/framework doesn't alter the html. btw try __View Page Source__ (`Ctrl + U`) in your browser, I'm sure you will be able to see the `darkDesign` class in `body` tag.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani when checking the page source the class is there

Comment: Do you have a _ViewStart.cshtml file and and is the expected _Layout.cshtml there? In the chrome output I also would have expected the darkdesign class to be shown in the image above, unless some js is stripping that class out.

Comment: @VargaDev, I successfully rendered the body style based on your needs. Please tell us the specific content of your `darkDesign` style and where you put the style code, and make sure that the page you test uses the layout template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in not Razor, as @Wiktor-Zychla mentioned, `RenderBody` doesn't dynamically render the body *tag*. (the Body in RenderBody means the page/layout content/body)

Also as I mentioned in the comment section, the `<!--Loader starts-->` part is not in your source (Razor), so `darkDesign` class removed by JS when you visit the page in the browser. as you confirmed, you should be able to see `darkDesign` class in `body` tag in page source. (in your browser hit `Ctrl + U` to see the page source)

So

- If you using some JS library/framework (or jQuery plugin), you should check their documentation to see why they removed class from `body`. maybe you can disabled this behavior or tell them to add your class.
- Another way (easy and dirty one) is adding the class using JS, just make sure your code execure after their code.

You can mention which library/framework (or jQuery plugin) you using, then maybe I can help you more.